# Angular not updating *ngFor Loop

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to list some concerts in the HTML which I get from a web API (this part works). The API is wrapped inside a `ConcertService`:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConcertService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  upcoming() {
    return this.http.get<Concert[]>(environment.concerts.upcoming_url);
  }
}
```

I use this service in my `ConcertsComponent` which looks like the following:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-concerts',
  templateUrl: './concerts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./concerts.component.scss'],
})
export class ConcertsComponent implements OnInit {
  private _date_formatting_options: any = {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: 'numeric',
  };

  concerts: Concert[] = [];

  constructor(private _concertService: ConcertService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._concertService.upcoming().subscribe((data) => (this.concerts = data));
  }

  createDay(concert: Concert): string {
    return new Date(concert.date).toLocaleDateString(
      'de-DE',
      this._date_formatting_options
    );
  }

  play_time(concert: Concert): string {
    return (
      concert.start_time.substr(0, 5) +
      ' Uhr - ' +
      concert.end_time.substr(0, 5) +
      ' Uhr | ' +
      concert.description.organizer
    );
  }
}
```

This is the `concerts.component.html`:

```html
<ul id="gig-list">
  <li *ngFor="let concert of concerts">
    <span class="band bold">
      {{ concert.band_name }}
    </span>
    <span class="date bold">
      {{ concert.date }}
    </span>
    <span class="description">
      {{ play_time(concert) }}
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>

<p>Amount of upcoming concerts: {{concerts.length}}</p>
```

My problem now is that once the `ConcertService` fetches the data and makes them available in the `ConcertsComponent` only the `<p>`-tag updates and shows the correct value. In the HTML the `<ul>`-tag is empty.

What can I do for the `*ngFor` directive to work properly? The `CommonModule` from `@angular/common` is imported in the coresponding module.

EDIT:

Here is the `console.log(data)` from inside of ngOnInit. These are fake values that come from my dev backend/database. But they are formatted the way they are suppost to.
[image: the console.log(data) inside ngOnInit]

Comment: Do you know that all the concerts have a truthy `start_time` and `end_time`? If not, `play_time` might throw an error...

Comment: Could you add console.log of the data response?

Comment: look at your console. check for errors. console.log your data to make sure its in the format you expect.

Comment: I'd like to see the url where the data comes from.

Comment: Inside of ngOnInit, console.log(data) to see what is returns.

Comment: @AndyBonner I know that every concert has a `start_time` and `end_time`

Comment: @Auguste I don't have any errors in the console.

Comment: can you add your work in https://stackblitz.com/ for easy debugging?

Comment: @GauravGupta https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-yhrefn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. The problem was that my API returned an JSON object in the form of

```js
{
  start_time: string,
  end_time: string,
  date: string,
  band_name: string
  location: {
    plz: number,
    street: string,
    number: string,
    name: string
  },
  descriptions: {
    organizer: string,
    place: string,
  }
}
```

but my `Concert` interface looked like this:

```
export interface Concert {
  date: string;
  start_time: string;
  end_time: string;
  band_name: string;
  location: {
    street: string;
    number: string;
    plz: number;
    name: string;
  };
  description: {
    organizer: string;
    place: string;
  };
}
```

so the error was a spelling mistake in the word `description`. I was missing a `s` at the end.